# InnoDB transaction isolation level in concurrent connections

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, isolation-level

I'm trying to figure out if this is an isolation issue, and how I can solve it. Suppose I have a database with 2 concurrent connections:

```
 0. BEGIN transaction TX1
 1. TX1 performs SELECT VALUE 10
 2. TX1 performs INSERT VALUE 10 since it does not exist
 3. TX1 performs SELECT VALUE 20
 4. TX1 performs INSERT VALUE 20 since it does not exist
 5. BEGIN transaction TX2 in a different session, using a different connection
 6. TX2 performs SELECT VALUE 10
 7. TX2 performs INSERT VALUE 10 since TX1 hasn't committed yet
 8. COMMIT TX2
 9. COMMIT TX1
```

The current isolation level is repeatable read. Can I solve this issue by changing to a different isolation level? if yes, which would be? read uncommitted?

Comment: Is value a unique key? Try `select VALUE FROM TABLE *FOR UPDATE*` in order to lock your results you got on the select query, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Why are you using 2 connections? Are they connected to separate servers (master/slave)?

Comment: @MrTux yes, value is a unique key. Will try FOR UPDATE, thanks.

Comment: @Jaydee one server only, however, two separate concurrent client connections.

Comment: It depends on how you want the system to fail. as MrTux says the best way to handle this is to lock the records you are about to update. Then TX2 will fail when the insert is attempted.

Comment: @Jaydee no, with `for update` the second transaction will block until the first transaction is committed or rolled back at step 6. Anyway, in OP the second transaction will block at step 7 - but in this case it will succeed or fail depending on TX1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to formulate my comment as a longer explanation. Preconditions: InnoDB and VALUE has a unique key or primary key.

Starting with the OPs example

```
 0. BEGIN transaction TX1
 1. TX1 performs SELECT VALUE 10
 2. TX1 performs INSERT VALUE 10 since it does not exist
 3. TX1 performs SELECT VALUE 20
 4. TX1 performs INSERT VALUE 20 since it does not exist
 5. BEGIN transaction TX2 in a different session, using a different connection
 6. TX2 performs SELECT VALUE 10
 7. TX2 performs INSERT VALUE 10 since TX1 hasn't committed yet
    TX2 will block here until TX1 finishes, if TX1 rolls back this step succeedes,
    if TX1 commits, you get an error here.
```

To prevent this situation use the `FOR UPDATE` postfix for the `SELECT` query:

```
 0. BEGIN transaction TX1
 1. TX1 performs SELECT VALUE 10 FOR UPDATE
 2. TX1 performs INSERT VALUE 10 since it does not exist
 3. TX1 performs SELECT VALUE 20 FOR UPDATE
 4. TX1 performs INSERT VALUE 20 since it does not exist
 5. BEGIN transaction TX2 in a different session, using a different connection
 6. TX2 performs SELECT VALUE 10 FOR UPDATE
    based on the `FOR UPDATE` condition, TX2 will block here until TX1 finishes.
    If TX1 commits, the result will be the row TX1 committed, if TX1 rolls back,
    this query returns an empty result.
```

By using the `FOR UPDATE` keywords you can avoid that TX2 fails and always uses the most current data - it causes row locks to be created (so, use with care). However, be aware of deadlocks ([Database Deadlock in SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324347/database-deadlock-in-select-for-update); always "lock" in the same order)

Comment: Although the select/insert process substantially slows down for multiple connections opened (tried with ~20 client connections), it does fixes the issue. Any alternatives to this? Thanks.