# Lock multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, locking

Is it possible to lock multiple rows in postgresql in a single shot against updating? I went through the official locks and can find locks which work on a table level and row level, but nothing on multiple rows.

Is it possible to do that in postgresql?

Comment: `select ... for update` - or even more efficient: just update those rows and they will be locked until you commit your transaction.

Comment: Befare of deadlock when locking multiple rows  (in parallel) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324347/database-deadlock-in-select-for-update

Answer (score 5):

Raed in the documentation: [The Locking Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)

Example:

```
select *
from my_table
where id < 10
for update
```